# Discussion Board Web Part items' URLs wrong after WSS 3.0 to SharePoint Foundation 2010 migration

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, wss-3.0, discussion-board

I recently migrated from WSS 3.0 to SharePoint Foundation 2010 without any website-breaking changes. The only issue I've run into so far is that the URL for two Discussion Board Web Parts on the SharePoint home page have incorrect links.

The two Web Parts are essentially stock Discussion Board Web Parts added to the home page.
On the old SharePoint site (running on WSS 3.0), each list item had a url similar to:

```
http://192.168.4.223/Lists/Team%20Discussion/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=%2fLists%2fTeam%20Discussion%2fSchedule&FolderCTID=0x01200200E8BF3AE7AA1C7548B1DEE2CA1003E22F
```

Clicking on the item in the Web Part would successfully take you to appropriate discussion.

On SharePoint Foundation 2010, after the migration, the links are as follows:

```
http://192.168.4.223/default.aspx?RootFolder=%2FLists%2FTeam%20Discussion%2FSchedule&FolderCTID=0x01200200E8BF3AE7AA1C7548B1DEE2CA1003E22F&View={41E4E9EC-FE4D-481C-A512-5971C2E252EF}
```

Clicking the link takes you back to the home page and the Web Part now shows

> There are no items to show in this view of the "Bulletin Board" discussion board. To add a new item, click "Add new discussion".

instead of taking you to the discussion board.

However, if I go to the "Bulletin Board" from the Quick Launch bar and select that same topic, the link is

```
http://192.168.4.223/Lists/Team%20Discussion/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=%2FLists%2FTeam%20Discussion%2FSchedule&FolderCTID=0x01200200E8BF3AE7AA1C7548B1DEE2CA1003E22F
```

which, if you look closely, is exactly the link as on WSS 3.0.

---

With all that said, is there any way to fix the links for those Web Parts such that users can click on the item instead of having to go through Quick Launch?

Comment: If you have solved this issue, please post the answer here! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was a simple fix.

For the web part that is exhibiting the behavior:

1. Click on the drop-down arrow and select Edit Web Part
2. Change "Selected View" from "<current view>" to, say, "Subject", then press Apply. This will reset the view to the default "Subject" view.
3. Click "Edit the current view" and adjust the columns/items displayed/etc. to match the view prior to resetting it (or to your desire).

After that, even though the URLs to each discussion board item still in the format of what I thought was wrong, the links work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem! After hours of searching I found this:

I've created a list definition (based on sharepoints own discussion list, form 14 hive), list instance and a module with the spesific discussion list

In the schema.xml I created a new view , based on baseview id 3.  If you don't base your list definitin on Type="108"   (templatetype 108) if would not work!

And another thing! 
Do not even try to change the baseviewid from other than 3   ( BaseviewID="3" ), if you ex in the module change it form 3 to 100 everything gets messed up!